# Prove W is a subspace of V.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If W₁ ⊆ W₂ ⊆ W₃......, where Wᵢ are the subspaces of a vector space V, and W = W₁ ∪ W₂ ∪......

Prove that W ≤ V.

So I proved that:
If W₁ and W₂ are two subspaces of V and W₁ ∪ W₂ ≤ V then W₁ ⊆ W₂ or W₂ ⊆ W₁.
(I let u ∈ W₁ - W₂ and v ∈ W₂ - W₁ and it was trivial)

Now I don't know how to use this to prove the problem.
I'm getting confused.
Maybe I don't have to use induction?

Comment: Uh... so this is trivial if there are only finitely many $W_i$ to consider... notice that $W= W_1\cup W_2\cup \dots \cup W_n = W_n$ and we were told that $W_n$is a subspace of $V$ already in the hypothesis.  So... the only confusion should be the infinite case... but the infinite case will act very similarly...

Comment: So... let us show that it is closed... suppose that $x\in W$ and that $y\in W$.  That means by definition that $x\in W_1\cup W_2\cup \dots$ so that means there must be some $m$ such that $x\in W_m$.  Similarly there must be some $n$ such that $y\in W_n$...  Now... suppose without loss of generality that $m\leq n$... so we have $x\in W_n$ and $y\in W_n$... can you finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, observe that $0 \in W_1$, so $0 \in W$. Next, for $x,y \in W$, fix $W_i$ and $W_j$ such that $x \in W_i$ and $y \in W_j$. Let $k$ be any index greater than $i$ and $j$, so that $x, y \in W_k$; hence, $x + y \in W_k \subset W$. Finally, given $x \in W$ and a scalar $\alpha$, fix $W_i$ such that $x \in W_i$, so $\alpha  x \in W_i \subset W$. We are

Answer (score 0):

If $W_1 \subset W_2$ then $W_1 \cup W_2=W_2$ and $W_2$ was a vector subspace by assumption. In infinite case you have to check the sub space axioms in $W= \cup W_i$. eg if $a , b \in W$, that $a+b \in W$. But if you take $a, b \in W$ there exist a $W_j$ with $a, b \in W_j$ and $W_j$ was a vector subspace...